# Using .load to fetch specific lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, github, github-pages

/What I'm trying to do is load specific lists on a (template)file into several pages. I want to have a template file with all lists that I can edit and affect all lists on on all pages. It seems what I need to do is use .load to fetch the lists. I tried the code listed on [this page](http://Load%20another%20page's%20list%20items%20into%20an%20ordered%20list.) titled "Load another page's list items into an ordered list.", but I can't seem to grasp what I need. I cannot use php as my host does not support it (github)

```js
   $( "#new-projects" ).load( "/ #Colors li" );
   $( "#new-projects" ).load( "/ #Numbers li" );
   $( "#new-projects" ).load( "/ #Misc li" );
```

```html
<ol id="new-projects">List:</ol>
<ol id="new-projects">List:</ol>
<ol id="new-projects">List:</ol>


My Template List file (listtemplate.html)

<div id="Colors">
        <li>blue</li>
        <li>black</li>
        <li>white</li>
      </div>
      
      <div id="Numbers">
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
      </div>

      <div id="Misc">
        <li>House</li>
        <li>Rake</li>
        <li>Hat</li>
      </div>
```

The code used on the .load info site I want to use to single out a certain list.

```
   $( "#new-projects" ).load( "/resources/load.html #projects li" );
```

Comment: Would work fine if the selector you use matched the html shown and the path to file is correct

Comment: ID's must be unique in a page. Inspect actual requests in browser dev tools network tab for clues